# today Ubuntu crashed 3 times

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Something I've never seen before: Ubuntu crashed 3 times today. The colors on the screen change around and there is no control via the mouse. Alt-T doesn't bring up a terminal. Nothing helps except pushing on the power off button.

I think it may be connected to Firefox since I always have Firefox on in gmail. I was looking at a MOOC in a different tab when a new mail came in and the system crashed the first time.
I didn't think too much of it and got the system back up and naturally turned on Firefox and gmail. Now I was looking at a movie when it crashed again. Again I brought up Firefox and continued on with the movie. Again it crashed. Now I had enough of Firefox so I finished the movie with no Firefox and no troubles.

This is too difficult to try and pin down so I just wanted to ask if anyone else has had troubles very recently. I put up a system monitor so I could see the use of the CPU. When it crashed the colors would change as usual, but the system monitor would no longer track the CPU usage. So it is more than just the mouse doesn't respond.

These are the only clues I have. Again, is anyone else having troubles?
Thanks,
Ilan

P.S. I added the tag 13.04 instead of 14.04 by mistake. I replaced 13.04 with 13.10 and then with 14.04

Comment: What a dumb mistake! I meant to click 14.04 and I clicked 13.04 instead. I always use the latest version.

Comment: Just a small comment: you mentioned Alt-T bringing up the terminal, but it's actually Ctrl+Alt+T. You can also access terminal through Ctrl+Alt+F1 , and actually F1 through F6 would work ,too. Just in case this is Firefox issue, try to reinstall it

Comment: Thanks. That was my typo, under pressure, when I forgot the Ctrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a it might be a graphics driver issue. Try using the proprietary drivers or the open source drivers:

- In the launcher, search for 'additional drivers' and launch it
- select a different driver for your graphics card, install and reboot. See if that fixed it.

Comment: I would just like to say what a real pleasure it is that there are so many great hearted people out there willing to help. It really does help!

Comment: The problem in the end was pure hardware. Like people with clogged arteries, computers suffer from dust. It crashed twice again this morning and the second time I didn't use Firefox. It still crashed. This is hardware. I took apart my computer vacuumed everything. I took out the memory and display card, cleaned them and used Servisol spray. Since I am replying to the question, it means that something worked.

Comment: I do agree that it was probably the display card - I have 2 monitors and need a display card. So I will mark your answer as correct even if it was a hardware problem and not a software problem. Again, I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Screen distortions are commonly caused by an overheating gpu, which would have been my second guess. Glad that it worked out for you.